# ARM Neon iOS floating-point conversion

Tags: ios, arm, neon

When I execute this code on my iPad Air (iOS 7.1)

```
#include <arm_neon.h>

static inline void TestArmConversion()
{
    float x[2] = { 1.5, 2.6 };
    int32_t z[2];

    vst1_s32(z, vcvt_f32_s32(vld1_f32(x)));

    for (int k = 0; k < 2; k++)
    {
        printf("z[%d] = %d\n", k, z[k]);
    }
}
```

...I get the following result:

```
z[0] = 1316945920
z[1] = 1317031117
```

I would have expected to get

z[0] = 1
   z[1] = 2

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were close! You just mixed up the conversion. Use `vcvt_s32_f32(float32x2_t)` instead.

Comment: Okay thanks, that solved my problem! :-) Would have expected the compiler to issue a type error.